# How can I run the Local Docker image with my local host DB & without docker compose yml

Tags: docker

I have only the Docker image file.
I don't have docker-compose.yml file. I want to test it my local database with the Docker image.
I tried to run the docker image with localhost database. But not able to connect my xampp Mysql

```
docker run -d -t -i -e MYSQL_DATABASE='database' -e MYSQL_HOSTNAME='localhost' -e MYSQL_PORT='3306' -e MYSQL_USER='root' -e MYSQL_PASSWORD='example' -p 8081:80 <DOCKERIMGID>
```

I tried 192.168.0.1 & 127.0.0.1, localhost, host.docker.internal

But, it's not working.

Answer (score 0):

At a first glance.
MYSQL_HOSTNAME should be "host.docker.internal" instead of "mysql".

You may also need to grant access to the database to 'root'@'%'.

Comment: I tried it with localhost, host.docker.internal & 127.0.0.1   But no luck

Comment: What is the exact error that you're getting?

Comment: It's not connecting with my xampp local sever DB. it's still searching the DB.

Comment: Yes, i have removed all the Docker image  & i tried to connect the DB using host.docker.internal . now it's working fine.